# Image gallery with thumnail and two captions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image-gallery

I need to design gallery in similar to example below with responsive feature.

[image]

so far i managed to find few galleries but each one had one or the other limitation. Gallery i am working on is based on jssor example http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.html

I am able to make some modification to the code and make it similar to my requirement, Unfortunately same code which is working on my local system is not working on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77uuamcn/3/).

At present i tried to add the caption to the jssor gallery but it is not working, while my actual requirement is for two separate caption one will show the title of the image & other will be link to a website or web page...

I would appreciate help in this regarding or a gallery which is similar to my requirement I have spend two days trying to get my hands on good code which can be easy to customize to my design.

Code sample:

```
<div style="width:1000px; background-color:green; margin-top:30px;">
    <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
    <!-- You can move inline styles to css file or css block. -->
    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1000px;  height: 480px; overflow: hidden;">
        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;"></div>
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;  top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left:0; top: 0px; width: 550px; height: 480px; overflow: hidden;">
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/01.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/thumb-01.jpg" />    <span> Title</span>

            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/02.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/thumb-02.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/03.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/thumb-03.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/04.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/thumb-04.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/05.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/thumb-05.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/06.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/thumb-06.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/07.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/thumb-07.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/08.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/thumb-08.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/09.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/thumb-09.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/10.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/thumb-10.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/11.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/thumb-11.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/12.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/thumb-12.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/13.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/thumb-13.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/14.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/travel/thumb-14.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Arrow Left --> <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 140px; left: 10px;">
        </span>

        <!-- Arrow Right --> <span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 140px; left: 490px">
        </span>

        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
        <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin 02 Begin -->
        <div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort02" style="position: absolute; width: 430px; height: 480px; right:0px; bottom: 0px; margin-left:2px;">
            <div u="slides" style="cursor: move;" class="thumbnail-custom">
                <div u="prototype" class="p" style="position: absolute; width: 99px; height: 66px; top: 0; left: 0;">
                    <div class=w>
                        <thumbnailtemplate style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></thumbnailtemplate>
                    </div>
                    <div class=c></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
        </div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin End -->
    </div>
    <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove the unwanted '/' at line 42 of scripts.

And make following changes,

1. Add css for captions

   ```
   /* caption css */
   .captionOrange, .captionBlack
   {
       color: #fff;
       font-size: 20px;
       line-height: 30px;
       text-align: center;
       border-radius: 4px;
   }
   .captionOrange
   {
       background: #EB5100;
       background-color: rgba(235, 81, 0, 0.6);
   }
   .captionBlack
   {
       font-size:16px;
       background: #000;
       background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   }
   a.captionOrange, A.captionOrange:active, A.captionOrange:visited
   {
       color: #ffffff;
       text-decoration: none;
   }
   a.captionOrange:hover
   {
       color: #eb5100;
       text-decoration: underline;
       background-color: #eeeeee;
       background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.7);
   }
   ```
2. Add caption options

   ```
   $CaptionSliderOptions: {
       $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,
       $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,
       $PlayInMode: 1,
       $PlayOutMode: 3
   }
   ```
3. Add captions to slide

   ```
   <div u=caption t="L" du="2000" class="captionOrange" style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 300px; width:500px; height:30px;"> Caption 1 </div>
   <a u="caption" t="R" class="captionOrange" href="http://www.yourdomain.com" style="position: absolute; top: 300px; left: 630px; width: 250px; height: 30px;">www.yourdomain.com</a>
   ```

See http://jsfiddle.net/77uuamcn/4/

Comment: Woh! It is you am i lucky... Thanks you so much.. You have a great script i wish you can add this theme to your collection.

Comment: Jssor, It doesnt show caption for other thumbnails for some reason and how can i show caption without any effect,  Just fade effect. I also tried to play with teh class of Caption so that i can put the second caption under the first caption but nothing works.

Comment: please remove u=caption to disable caption animation.

Comment: See step 3, I added caption to one slide, you can add caption for other slides.

Comment: Thanks. Removing animation was easy.

Comment: How can caption be moved under the large image so that Title caption & website caption can be placed under each other.  http://jsfiddle.net/77uuamcn/7/ I tried to play around and noticed that removing `overflow: hidden;` css property breaks the design. is there possible way we can show caption at bottom of image rather than on image itself

Comment: You can remove 'u="image"' and specify small image size manually by css. Thus the image size is smaller than slide, then you have space to place caption aside.

Comment: I was afraid that could be the only solution, I had thought of it to upload images of fixed size  in slide container & then increase the higt to show captions. I could think of this as a fix but what if some one wants to put navigation under the thumbnail images. anyways thanks

Comment: Navigators are out of 'slides' container. Note that 'outer container' maintains 'slides' container, bullet navigator, arrow navigator and thumbnail navigator.