# jssor gallery not working with thumbnails and captions together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jssor

I'm looking for an answer for my question for 3 days now and so far didn't find a good answer.
The closest I found is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233355/image-gallery-with-thumnail-and-two-captions) but it didn't work for me.
I'm using jssor gallery and I need the gallery to work as described in example link
[gallery with thumbnails under the main image and caption at the bottom of the image](http://3444-keshet.2beweb.co.il/vault/images1/gallery_example.jpg)
I could make the gallery with the thumbnails and with the caption working separately but when I tried to combine the two it didn't work.

This is the code I used for the gallery with thumbs and caption:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                var _CaptionTransitions = [];
                _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|B"] = { $Duration: 800, $Clip: 8, $Move: true, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutExpo };

                var options = {
                    $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                    $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
                    
                        $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                        $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                        $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                        $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                        $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                    }
                  
                  $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable thumbnail navigator or not
                        $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                        $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                        $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
                        $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                        $DisplayPieces: 10,                             //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
                        $ParkingPosition: 360                           //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
                    }

                };

                var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
            });
```

```css
 .jssort01 .w
              {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
              }
              .jssort01 .c {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 122px;
                height: 74px;
                border: #000 2px solid;
              }
              .jssort01 .p:hover .c, .jssort01 .pav:hover .c, .jssort01 .pav .c {
                background: url(/vault/js/t01.png) center center;
                border-width: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 122px;
                height: 74px;
              }
              .jssort01 .p:hover .c, .jssort01 .pav:hover .c {
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 122px;
                height: 74px;
                border: #fff 2px solid;
              }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
          <div id="slider1_container" style="display: none; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 676px; height: 415px; overflow: hidden;">
            <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 676px; height: 415px;
                                   overflow: hidden;">
    <div>
      <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/001.jpg" alt="" />
      <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/001.jpg" />
      <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute; top: 365px; left: 0px; right: 0; width: 676px; height: 50px; background: #000; opacity: 0.5; color: #fff;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);">
                        </div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            color: White; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                            #photodescription#
                        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/002.jpg" alt="" />
      <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/002.jpg" />
      <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute; top: 365px; left: 0px; right: 0; width: 676px; height: 50px; background: #000; opacity: 0.5; color: #fff;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);">
                        </div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            color: White; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                            #photodescription#
                        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/003.jpg" alt="" />
      <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/003.jpg" />
      <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute; top: 365px; left: 0px; right: 0; width: 676px; height: 50px; background: #000; opacity: 0.5; color: #fff;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);">
                        </div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            color: White; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                            #photodescription#
                        </div>
    </div>
    </div> 
    <div>
      <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/004.jpg" alt="" />
      <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/004.jpg" />
      <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute; top: 365px; left: 0px; right: 0; width: 676px; height: 50px; background: #000; opacity: 0.5; color: #fff;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);">
                        </div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            color: White; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                            #photodescription#
                        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div>
      <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/005.jpg" alt="" />
      <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/005.jpg" />
      <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute; top: 365px; left: 0px; right: 0; width: 676px; height: 50px; background: #000; opacity: 0.5; color: #fff;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);">
                        </div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            color: White; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                            #photodescription#
                        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div>
      <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/006.jpg" alt="" />
      <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/006.jpg" />
      <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute; top: 365px; left: 0px; right: 0; width: 676px; height: 50px; background: #000; opacity: 0.5; color: #fff;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);">
                        </div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            color: White; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                            #photodescription#
                        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div>
      <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/007.jpg" alt="" />
      <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/007.jpg" />
      <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute; top: 365px; left: 0px; right: 0; width: 676px; height: 50px; background: #000; opacity: 0.5; color: #fff;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);">
                        </div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            color: White; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                            #photodescription#
                        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div>
      <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/008.jpg" alt="" />
      <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/008.jpg" />
      <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute; top: 365px; left: 0px; right: 0; width: 676px; height: 50px; background: #000; opacity: 0.5; color: #fff;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);">
                        </div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            color: White; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                            #photodescription#
                        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div>
      <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/009.jpg" alt="" />
      <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/009.jpg" />
      <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute; top: 365px; left: 0px; right: 0; width: 676px; height: 50px; background: #000; opacity: 0.5; color: #fff;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);">
                        </div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            color: White; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                            #photodescription#
                        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div>
      <img u="image" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/010.jpg" alt="" />
      <img u="thumb" src="http://www.jssor.com/img/photography/010.jpg" />
      <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute; top: 365px; left: 0px; right: 0; width: 676px; height: 50px; background: #000; opacity: 0.5; color: #fff;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);">
                        </div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50px;
                            color: White; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                            #photodescription#
                        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin Begin -->
            <div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort01" style="position: absolute; width: 800px; height: 100px; left:0px; bottom: 0px;">
            
                <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
                <div u="slides" style="cursor: move;">
                    <div u="prototype" class="p" style="position: absolute; width: 72px; height: 72px; top: 0; left: 0;">
                        <div class=w><div u="thumbnailtemplate" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></div></div>
                        <div class=c>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
            </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin End -->
            
            
          </div>
          <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
```

Would appreciate if my question will not be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

1. A `,` is missing in your js code. Please replace

   ```
   $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
       $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
       $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
       $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
       $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
       $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
       $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
       $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
       $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
   },
   ```
2. Remove `display: none;` from `slider1_container`.

   Replace

   ```
   <div id="slider1_container" style="display: none;
   ```

   with

   ```
   <div id="slider1_container" style="
   ```

Comment: one other problem  occured, the thumbnail are not moving, ican darg them but they are allways comming back to the same place insted of moving and stopping in a different location.

Comment: here is a link to my project:

Comment: If $DisplayPieces is more than slides number, it can't loop. Please replace `$DisplayPieces: 20` with `$DisplayPieces: 5`.

Comment: last quastion, can i make the thumbnails move with left and right arrows?

Comment: Yes, you can. http://www.jssor.com/demos-jquery/thumbnail-navigator-with-arrows.source.html